# Python: write line to file, that combine with different types

Tags: python

I have json, it contains next keys

```
[u'domain', u'_timestamp', u'meta_tags', u'author', u'title', u'url', u'tags', u'flow', u'link_tags', u'content', u'post_id', u'flags', u'polling', u'published', u'hubs', u'_id']
```

I need to writelines from it to `.vw` file.
But some of them are numeric, and some string. And I need to save this types.

Also I have file with values of `target`

```
url     target
vk.com    0.934250
```

I use

```
targets = train_target.target.values.tolist()
with open('train.json') as inp_json, \
 open('habr_train.vw', 'w') as out_vw:
    for i, line in enumerate(tqdm_notebook(inp_json)):
        data_json = json.loads(line)

        if data_json['flow'] is None and data_json['author']['nickname'] is None:
            res_line = str(targets[i]) + ' |title ' + data_json['title'] + ' |tags ' + ' '.join(data_json['tags']) \
              + ' |domain ' + data_json['domain'] + ' |flow None' + ' |author None' + ' |hubs ' + data_json['hubs'][0]['title'] + ' |num content_len:' + str(round(len(data_json['content']) / 1000000, 1)) + ' month:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).month) + ' hour:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).hour) + '\n'

        elif data_json['flow'] is None:
            res_line = str(targets[i]) + ' |title ' + data_json['title'] + ' |tags ' + ' '.join(data_json['tags']) \
              + ' |domain ' + data_json['domain'] + ' |flow None' + ' |author ' + data_json['author']['nickname'] + ' |hubs ' + data_json['hubs'][0]['title'] + ' |num content_len:' + str(round(len(data_json['content']) / 1000000, 1)) + ' month:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).month) + ' hour:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).hour) + '\n'

        elif data_json['author']['nickname'] is None:
            res_line = str(targets[i]) + ' |title ' + data_json['title'] + ' |tags ' + ' '.join(data_json['tags']) \
              + ' |domain ' + data_json['domain'] + ' |flow ' + data_json['flow'] + ' |author None' + ' |hubs ' + data_json['hubs'][0]['title'] + ' |num content_len:' + str(round(len(data_json['content']) / 1000000, 1)) + ' month:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).month) + ' hour:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).hour) + '\n'

        else:
            res_line = str(targets[i]) + ' |title ' + data_json['title'] + ' |tags ' + ' '.join(data_json['tags']) \
              + ' |domain ' + data_json['domain'] + ' |flow ' + data_json['flow'] + ' |author ' + data_json['author']['nickname'] + ' |hubs ' + data_json['hubs'][0]['title'] + ' |num content_len:' + str(round(len(data_json['content']) / 1000000, 1)) + ' month:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).month) + ' hour:' + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).hour) + '\n'

        out_vw.write(res_line.encode('utf-8'))
```

It works, but next I need to use library and it returns me error, that str(targets[i]) should be float.

Is any way to save types of values?
How can I fix that?

Comment: can you please post the error traceback ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of use the concatenate operator you can use `format` to avoid those kind of errors

**example**:

```
res_line = '{0} |title {1} |tags {2} |domain {3} |flow None |author None |hubs {4} |num content_len: {5} month: {6} hour: {7}\n'.format(str(targets[i]),data_json['title'], ' '.join(data_json['tags']), data_json['domain'], data_json['hubs'][0]['title'], str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).month), str(datetime.fromtimestamp(data_json['_timestamp']).hour))
```